# What is wrong with this tabularx?

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, line-spacing

I hate tables in LaTeX!  I'm always getting into some troubles, and yet this should be easy:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Title}
        \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textsf{Day 1}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 2}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 3}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 4}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 5}}
        \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text 1}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 2}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 3}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 4}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 5}
        \\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Preview of the trouble:

[image]

As the picture shows, the table doesn't close on the right side.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: no need for the tabularx since there is no balancing of text in columns -- also i feel you should remove all verticals for better impact -- also remove all singular multicolumns

Comment: Why do you encase each and every cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` directive? This completely negates the capabilities of the `X` column type.

Comment: You do not have any X cells. tabularx can do nothing useful for such a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked,

> What is wrong with the code?

The code encases (entombs?) each and every cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` wrapper, thereby completely overriding the `X` column type's ability to provide automatic line breaking inside the cells. In consequence, there's absolutely no reason to expect the width of the `tabularx` environment to equal `\textwidth`.

The remedy? You need to (a) get rid of the `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` wrappers, so that the `tabularx` machinery can actually do its job, and (b) define and employ a version of the `X` column type which centers rather than fully justifies the cell contents. See the code below for ways to satisfy the second condition.

For the example at hand, reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` -- the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace -- by half succeeds in avoiding line breaks in the final row. See the second `tabularx` example in the following screenshot for the resulting "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in}, left=1.5in,top=0.5in, 
            includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
% Define a centered version of 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} 
% or: \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|}} % <-- "C", not "X"
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\texttt{tabularx} with default value of \texttt{\string\tabcolsep}}
    \\ \hline
    \textsf{Day 1}
    & \textsf{Day 2} & \textsf{Day 3} & \textsf{Day 4} & \textsf{Day 5}
    \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|}
    Text 1 & Text 2 & Text 3 & Text 4 & Text 5 \\
    12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|}} % <-- "C", not "X"
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\texttt{tabularx} with reduced value of \texttt{\string\tabcolsep}}
    \\ \hline
    \textsf{Day 1}
    & \textsf{Day 2} & \textsf{Day 3} & \textsf{Day 4} & \textsf{Day 5}
    \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|}
    Text 1 & Text 2 & Text 3 & Text 4 & Text 5 \\
    12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00 & 12h00 to 18h00
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There’s no way I could have found this by  myself!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Title}
        \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textsf{Day 1}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 2}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 3}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 4}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsf{Day 5}}
        \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text 1}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 2}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 3}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 4}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text 5}
        \\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12h00 to 18h00}
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach will, in general, *not* limit the overall width of the tabular material to `\textwidth` -- which, presumably, was the OP's reason for using a `tabularx` environment. (To verify this assertion, add the option `showframe` while loading the `geometry` package and recompile.)

Comment: why use `\multicolumn` in every cell to replace the default column alignment by the same alignment?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the table to get the same lenght as the text width.